# How to get a specific value which dependets on different values of a data feed?

Tags: mysql, output, case

I am trying to get the following logic using `MySql`. I am going to write in psedocode then show you what I have done and what is the expected result.

```
when Country = 'Spain' 
take  the Value where the Property = Status A
else take the Value where Property = Status B
```

I have two tables I am going to show you what do they consist of however the data will not real due to data sensitivity.

**Table 1**

```
|ID | Country|
:---|-------:|
|123| Spain  |
|456| Italy  |
```

**Table 2**

```
|ID |Property Code | Value|
|:--|:------------:|-----:|
|123| Property A   | Red  |
|456| Property A   | Grey |
|456| Property B   | Blue |
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
|ID |Country       | Value|
|:--|:------------:|-----:|
|123| Spain        | Red  |
|456| Italy        | Blue |
```

**Current Code Used**

```
select distinct
  t1.ID ,t1.Country
 ,case when t1.Country = 'Spain' and t2.PropertyCode = 'Property A' then t2.Value
       when t1.Country <> 'Spain' and t2.PropertyCode = 'Property B' then t2.Value else '' end as Value
from table1 t1

left join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

**Current Output**

```
|ID |Country       | Value|
|:--|:------------:|-----:|
|123| Spain        | Red  |
|456| Italy        | Blue |
|456| Italy        |      |
```

Can someone help with this I don't want to get duplicate values, I am pretty sure I am using the case when in correctly. I want one row for every `ID` as shown in the *Expected Outcome* above.

Thank you.

Comment: Simplify your life create a select for spain and union a select for not spain

Answer (score 0):

Hey I managed to find a solution to this:

```
  t1.ID ,t1.Country
 ,case when t1.Country = 'Spain' and t2.PropertyCode = 'Property A' then t2.Value
       when t1.Country <> 'Spain' and t2.PropertyCode = 'Property B' then t2.Value else '' end as Value
from table1 t1

left join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID

where (t1.Country = 'Spain' and t2.PropertyCode = 'Property A'
   or t1.Country <> 'Spain' and t2.PropertyCode = 'Property B')
```

hope this helps people other there! :)